# Firebase functions not loading .env file

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

According to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), `Loaded environment variables from .env.` should be printed to the console when deploying functions. My functions are exported inside `src/functions/functions.ts`. This is specified in my `package.json` file:
`main: lib/src/functions/functions.js` (since I am using TypeScript, I have to specify the generated javascript file inside `lib`).

I have tried to locate the .env files inside the root directory, and inside the `src/functions/` folder. None of them works. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am facing the same issue any luck?

Comment: Hey! It worked for me after upgrading to a minimum version of v 10.2.0 for firebase-tools :D So make sure to update it!

Comment: @erikkjer I am using the latest 11.8.0 and its not loading for me either

Comment: Guys make sure you check it after the build. If you have some error handling, in build for some reason variables don't get loaded

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem. I was able to solve it by moving the .env files to the base of the project.

Example:

- functions/.env
- functions/.env.qa
- functions/.env.dev
- functions/.env.etc

Hope it helps you
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xJN9.png)

Edit: removed the extra '.' after .env

Comment: Is it possible without moving the .env to the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turns out the `firebase-tools` version installed globally which where used for deploy where not updated by `npm install -g firebase-tools`.

Solution:

1. Confirm the `firebase-tools` versions: `firebase --version` which should be more than 11
2. Check where is the binary: `which firebase`
3. If it's in `/usr/local/bin/firebase` run `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/firebase`
4. If it's in some node-related folder, try to `npm uninstall -g firebase-tools`
5. Reinstall: `npm install -g firebase-tools`
6. Confirm location and version: `firebase --version`. As of 1st Oct 2022: 11.13.0

Comment: doesn't work with firebase-tools 11.19.0 nor 11.20.0 :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to move your .env file to your root directory.
2. In the file you need your environment variable, run this

```
import dotenv from "dotenv"; (ES Modules)
```

or

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv); ( CommonJs )
```

then

```
dotenv.config({ path: {PATH to your .env file})
```

In case you don't know how to get the path: right-click your .env file in vscode => choose Copy Path

Your environment should work properly